# Control on dimension of image

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces, approximation-theory, dimension-theory

Let $f:E\rightarrow F$ be a map between Banach spaces E and F; E finite dimensional (>0) and F infinite dimensional.  Let $F$ be equipped with its weak topology and suppose that $f$ is strong-weak continuous.

Under what additional conditions can we guarantee that $\operatorname{span}(f(E))$ is a *finite-dimensional* subspace of F?

Comment: For linear maps this is trivial and for non-linear maps this seems to be hopeless.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth The first part I also noticed (obv. from splitting lemma) and I expect the second may follow for weak-strong continuous maps which are sufficiently Frechet differentiable..

Comment: @Wasserstein'sApprentice: Just curious: what do you mean by "splitting lemma" in this context?)

Comment: I mean, the linear algebraic splitting lemma to infer that the image of $f$ (if linear) is a finite-dimensional subspace of its codomain; then you use the fact that maps between finite-dimensional linear spaces are (weakly) continuous...so any linear map is strong-weakly continuous and has finite dimensional image

Comment: @Wasserstein'sApprentice: Thanks for your reply! I'm just wondering why you would like to apply the splitting lemma here: a linear image of a finite-dimensional space is obviously finitely generated and thus finite-dimensional - so no need to split anything ;-). But admittedly, that's a bit nitpicking, and it leads away from your actual question.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Fair enough; I was just having fun with over-powered ways to show simple things (like just keeping track of the basis of the image under the linear map)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to give an example on how weird this can become: take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $F = \ell^2$ with standard Hilbert basis $e_0 e_1, e_2, \ldots$. Then take a smooth bump function $\chi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with support in the unit interval and, say  $\chi(1/2) = 1$ to make things non-trivial.

Define the highly non-linear but smooth as smooth can be map
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \chi(t-n) e_n
\end{equation}
Then the span of the image contains the Hilbert basis...

As a slight variation one can als consider a holomorphic example, e.g. by
\begin{equation}
g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} e_n
\end{equation}
Since the $e_n$ are unit vectors, this series is absolutely convergent for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. It is holomorphic as a vector-valued function: here weakly coincides with strongly anyway, but this can also to be seen elementary. Now the derivatives at $0$ are the basis vectors again, so there is no finite-dimensional subspace and no open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ containing $f(U)$: otherwise the derivatives would be in this subspace...

Maybe this example is a bit more illustrative since the first one has the
feature that *locally in $t$* the image is contained in finite-dimensional subspaces. This is not the case with $g$.

Comment: Ah, I don't know how to formalize my intuition; but your comment "highly-nonlinear" really hits the point.  Is there a (standard?) way of measuring how "far" a function is from being linear (possibly in terms of its dimension dilation)?

Comment: hmmm... Here I have no idea how to quantify "highly non-linear". It is smooth but non-analytic. But there are also holomorphic examples, I will update